# Equivalence of Maxwell and electric field operator in the Coulomb gauge (minimal and polar coupling)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

In the field theory literature, we find the interaction Hamiltonian coupling a point particle with charge $e$ and mass $m$ to the electromagnetic field to be

$$
\hat{H}_\text{int}(t)
=
-
\frac{e}{m}
\hat{p}^i(t)
\hat{A}_i(t,\boldsymbol{x})
\tag{1},
$$
wherein $\hat{p}^i(t)$ is the particle's $i$th momentum operator, and $\hat{A}_i(t,\boldsymbol{x})$ is the Maxwell field's $i$th field component in the Coulomb (transverse) gauge.

However, outside of field theory, e.g., in atomic physics, we find the interaction Hamiltonian to be

$$
\hat{H}_\text{int}(t)
=
-
e
\hat{x}^i
\hat{E}_i(t,\boldsymbol{x})
\tag{2},
$$
wherein $\hat{x}^i$ is the particle's $i$th position operator, and $\hat{E}_i(t,\boldsymbol{x})$ is the $i$th component of the electric field operator. Often the first two factors are defined as the electric dipole operator, $\hat{d}^i=-e\hat{p}^i$.

In *Quantum Optics* by Mandel & Wolf, the interaction Hamiltonian in eq. (1) is referred to as **minimal coupling** while the interaction Hamiltonian in eq. (2) is referred to as **polar coupling**.
Furthermore, Mandel & Wolf claim that there exists a unitary transformation

$$
\hat{U}
=
\exp\left\{
-ie\hat{x}^i\hat{A}(t,\boldsymbol{x})
\right\}
\tag{3}
$$

connecting these two couplings.
In *Photons and Atoms - Introduction to Quantumelectrodynamics* by Cohen-Tannoudji (p. 253), we find some more insights between the difference of the minimal and polar couplings. In particular, he claims that both descriptions are equivalent and correspond to different gauge conditions.

#### Questions

1. Is my understanding correct that the polar and minimal formalisms are equivalent?
2. Are there any limitations to this equivalence, for instance, second-order coupling $\hat{A}(t,\boldsymbol{x})^2$?
3. It appears to me that the "fundamental" fields are different in the minimal and polar description, Maxwell field, $\hat{A}$, vs electric field, $\hat{E}$. However, we usually say that the Maxwell field (or vector potential) is unphysical as we can change it by a gauge transformation. How do we resolve this contradiction?

**Update 1 (11.11.21)**

Addressing the feedback from [ACuriousMind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50583/acuriousmind)

> 1. What about the Cohen-Tannoudji argument you already seem to have found is insufficient for you?

Good point, the explanation requires quite some context, which might qualify for a separate question (I was hoping to avoid that).

In photodetection theory, we derive a relation between the photocurrent of a photodetector, e.g., a phototube or photodiode, from the atom-light interaction. Most authors, e.g., Cohen-Tannoudji et. al. in *Atom—Photon Interactions: Basic Process and Applications*,  use the polar coupling interaction, eq. (2).
Mandel & Wolf use the minimal coupling interaction, eq. (1).

In both cases, they find that the mean photocurrent is proportional to an intensity operator. However, depending on the field, the intensity operator is either given by the Maxwell or electric field, i.e.,

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{I}_A(t)
&=
\hat{A}^{(-)}(t)
\hat{A}^{(+)}(t)
&
\hat{I}_E(t)
&=
\hat{E}^{(-)}(t)
\hat{E}^{(+)}(t)
.
\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Mandel & Wolf address this issue by stating that they are related by
$$
\omega_0^2
\hat{I}_A
=
\hat{I}_E
$$
the same in the narrow-bandwidth approximation where the center-of-mass frequency is $\omega_0$.

**If we do not invoke the narrow-bandwidth approximation, we get different predictions depending on the interaction we started. It should be possible to determine if the photocurrent depends on the field frequency to rule out the polar coupling!**

> 2. Where would such a coupling come from? The overall action still has to be gauge-invariant!

Such a coupling usually appears when we couple the momentum of a charged particle with the field, i.e.,

$$
(p-eA)^2
=
p^2
-pA
-Ap
+e^2A^2
.\tag{5}
$$

> 3. Neither of these fields is "fundamental" in this case because you're not treating them as dynamical but as background fields here. But the "unphysical" vector potential appears as the central dynamical/fundamental field e.g. in the classical Lagrangian formulation of ED. What exactly is the "contradiction" you see here?

See my remark to your first question.

**Update 2 (13.11.21)**

Apparently, I was not clear about the photocurrent operator. Let me try to clarify.

In *Quantum optics* by Mandel & Wolf (p. 701), we have

[image: Quantum Optics by Mandel & Wolf (p. 701)]

which I believe misses a power of two over the $\omega_1$.

In [*Photodetection of polychromatic light* by Kimble & Mandel](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/4710/1/KIMpra84.pdf), we find eq. (4):

[image: Photodetection of polychromatic light by Kimble & Mandel]

These are **not** definitions but **predictions**. Depending on if we start with the minimal or polar coupling, eq. (1) or eq. (2), the photocurrent is either frequency-dependent or not!

In the quasi-monochromatic limit (narrow-bandwidth approximation) they are related by a multiplicative factor.

In principle, it should be possible to measure the (mean) photocurrent and see if there is any quadratic frequency dependence.

In practice, the frequency response of a photodiode (Google spectral sensitivity or responsitivity) might be much stronger compared to the frequency dependence between the photocurrent operators.

Comment: 1- What about the Cohen-Tannoudji argument you already seem to have found is insufficient for you? 2. Where would such a coupling come from? The overall action still has to be gauge-invariant! 3. Neither of these fields is "fundamental" in this case because you're not treating them as dynamical but as background fields here. But the "unphysical" vector potential appears as the central dynamical/fundamental field e.g. in the classical Lagrangian formulation of ED. What exactly is the "contradiction" you see here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I updated the question. Does this clarify your points? If you need any references let me know and I look them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the two formulations are equivalent, note that in Coulomb gauge, $A^0=0$ so $E_i = \partial_i A_0 - \partial_t A_i = - \dot{A}_i$.

Then using $p_i = m \dot{x}_i$, and defining $H_A$ to be the Hamilonian written in terms of $A$ and $H_E$ the Hamilontian written in terms of $E$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
H_A &=& -\frac{e}{m}p^i A_i \\
&=& -e \dot{x}^i A_i \\
&=& \frac{d}{dt}\left(e x^i A_i\right) + e x^i \dot{A}_i \\
&=& \frac{d}{dt}\left(e x^i A_i\right) - e x^i E_i \\
&=& H_E + \frac{dG}{dt}
\end{eqnarray}
where $G\equiv e x^i A_i$.
In other words, the two Hamiltonians differ by a total time derivative of the "q" variables in the $x,A$ description. This total time derivative can be removed with a canonical transformation using standard techniques.

Adding a higher order non-minimal  coupling like one that is $\sim A^2$ is of course possible, and you could formulate any gauge invariant coupling in terms of either $A$ or $E$ and $B$. The details will depend on the non-minimal coupling.

In terms of whether $E$ or $A$ is more fundamental, I would say that this is a matter of perspective and not really a physics question. On the one hand, $E$ is more directly related to observables in a lab and is gauge invariant. On the other hand, it is much easier to quantize electromagnetism in terms of the vector potential (I actually have never seen a quantization directly in terms of $E$ and $B$, although that doesn't mean it doesn't exist) and it is easier to understand subtle quantum effects like the Aaronhov-Bohm effect and magnetic monopoles in terms of $A$. In general, in field theory, there is an enormous degeneracy of equivalent descriptions related by *field redefinitions*, so one learns not to place too much weight in any one description in terms of fields and instead focus on observable quantities like the $S$-matrix that are invariant under such choices.

Note that if $\partial_t A_i = -E_i$, then you could equally say $E_i = -\int dt A_i$. Since $E_i$ is an observable, doesn't that make $A_i$ an observable? How can that be if $A_i$ is a gauge field? Well, actually, $A_i$ is an observable if you fix a gauge completely. The catch is that any expression you write with $A_i$ in that gauge will be wrong in any other gauge. So usually it's better to replace $A_i$ with $E_i$ in any expression you want to represent an observable, then you have a gauge invariant expression that's true in any gauge. This is similar to the trick in GR where you pick a coordinate system, derive a relationship that holds between quantities in that coordinate system, and then replace those quantities with tensors that are equal to the original quantities in that coordinate system, but which have nice transformation properties under changes of coordinates. The resulting tensor expression has to be true (since it reduces to the coordinate-dependent result you derived) but holds in any coordinate system (since, relations between tensors are coordinate-independent by design).

Comment: how do you explain the different predictions for the photocurrent?

Comment: @bodokaiser Why do you say these are two different *predictions*? To me it looks like two different *definitions* of the photocurrent operator. The definitions are clearly different since they are not equal in the narrow-bandwidth approximation. Regardless of how they are related in general, they can't be equal because of this. So to me it seems you haven't shown there is any problem. This is very much related to my last point about field redefinitions in my answer.

Comment: These are indeed *predictions*, i.e., the photocurrent operator is *derived* (not defined) from the interaction of an atom with light. Depending on the particular kind of interaction one arrives at these two different photocurrent operators!

Comment: @bodokaiser Then why does the author say the two versions are related in some limit? To me that sounds like they are both legitimate choices and neither one makes a wrong prediction. I don't know what to tell you, I'm not an expert in that specific application, but the couplings are equivalent and nothing physical can depend on your choice of variables, or your choice of gauge.

Comment: "In both cases, they find that the mean photocurrent is proportional to an intensity operator." (a) is the proportionality factor the same in both cases? (b) Is there some other experimental setup where can you directly measure the value of "the intensity operator" (since evidently the mean photocurrent observable depends on the intensity but is not actually equal to the intensity)?

Comment: It's a legitimate question to ask how the predictions can be the same, that has to be understood if you want to work in this area, but I don't think it can possibly be correct that the predictions are different. In addition to the fact that apparently both couplings are used and have been shown to be different, if they *were* different someone would have figured out which one was correct and the other one wouldn't be used.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what keeps me awake at night :D I added some more context, let me know if there is more I can do. It might be that the predictions are indeed the same and the $\omega^2$ is hidden in some "detection efficiency" constant (as you suggested). Physically, I would expect the photocurrent to be independent of the frequency (neglecting the bandgap characteristics of the material). Why should it be more likely for a photon with higher energy to excite a photoelectron?

Comment: Thinking more about it, I think that you are correct that both versions have different proportionality constant which somewhat contains the frequency-(in-)dependence. What is confusing is that it appears to me that the derivations usually invoke the narrow-bandwidth approximation for the proportionality constant.

Comment: @bodokaiser The general rule is that $\partial_t A_i = E_i$ in Coulomb gauge) For a narrowband source $A_i \sim e^{i \omega t}$, so $E \sim \omega^2 A$. For a broadband source, one could either work in the time domain and continue using the general rule involving a time derivative, or work in the frequency domain and represent the signal as a superposition of narrowband sources, each obeying $E \sim \omega^2 A$. Since electrodynamics is linear, using superposition one can get the general solution from a single frequency by superposition. Quantum optics folks sometimes leave that unsaid.

Comment: I agree that quantum optics folks are a bit sloppy about their assumed scope. How would you actually address that the generalized quadrature operator $X(\vartheta)=\int d\omega \hat{a}(\omega) e^{-i\vartheta}+\text{h.c.}$ is an observable directly related to the Maxwell field $A$ by phase-rotation? Doesn't this imply that $A$ is also measurable?

Comment: @bodokaiser Heh. If $\partial_t A_i = E_i$, then you could equally say $A_i = \int d t E_i$. Since $E_i$ is an observable, doesn't that make $A_i$ an observable? How can that be if $A_i$ is a gauge field? Well, actually, $A_i$ *is* an observable *if you fix a gauge completely*. The catch is that any expression you write with $A_i$ in that gauge will be wrong in any other gauge. So usually it's better to replace $A_i$ with $E_i$ in any expression you want to represent an observable, then you have a *gauge invariant* expression that's true in any gauge.

Comment: Can you add this last comment to your answer? I think this is extremely valuable! Can one say that fixing a gauge is similar to restricting ourselves to a certain coordinate system? For example, as long as we are in a stationary reference frame electrodynamics is perfectly described by the Maxwell field in the Coulomb gauge. We first run into problems when we have moving reference frames because then the prediction is frame-dependent.

Comment: @bodokaiser Sure, I can add it. And I very much agree with your analogy to coordinate systems. In fact in GR, a very common trick is to pick a coordinate system, derive a relationship that holds between quantities in that coordinate system, and then replace those quantities with tensors that are equal to the original quantities in that coordinate system, but which have nice transformation properties under changes of coordinates. The resulting tensor expression has to be true (since it reduces to the coordinate-dependent result you derived) but holds in any coordinate system (since, tensors).

Comment: In fact there is also a geometric way to view the vector potential as a geometric object (a connection on a fiber bundle made up of a product of Minkowski space and the group  $U(1)$). So this relationship with coordinate systems is not even really an analogy, it actually does represent a geometric picture of what's going on deep down.